# Setting up nodejs using puppet on vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am trying to instal node on a fresh vagrant box using puppet however when running the manifest i get the following errors on the box.

```
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $include_src is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use $include => { 'src' => false } instead
Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $required_packages is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use package resources instead.
Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $key_source is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use $key => { 'source' => https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key } instead.
Warning: Scope(Apt::Key[Add key: 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280 from Apt::Source nodesource]): $key_source is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Please use $source instead.
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.efiling.local
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.efiling.local
```

My vagrant file looks like this:

```
  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                    puppet module install puppetlabs-apt;
                    puppet module install puppetlabs/nodejs"
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
  end
```

This is my manifest file:

```
class { 'nodejs': }
```

The next part is to get vagrant to run the manifest file but I believe these errors are stopping this from happening.

This is all relatively new to me so looking for some guidance on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `puppetlabs/nodejs` by `puppetlabs-nodejs` so your Vagrantfile will look like

```
  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                    puppet module install puppetlabs-apt;
                    puppet module install puppetlabs-nodejs"
  end
```

Which version of puppet are you using ? I had to upgrade to newer version on my ubuntu box to make it work, I upgrade to puppet v3.8.4 to make it work - see below the log

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
==> default:    (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in `issue_deprecation_warning')
==> default: Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
==> default: Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $include_src is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use $include => { 'src' => false } instead
==> default: Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $required_packages is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use package resources instead.
==> default: Warning: Scope(Apt::Source[nodesource]): $key_source is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use $key => { 'source' => https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key } instead.
==> default: Warning: Scope(Apt::Key[Add key: 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280 from Apt::Source nodesource]): $key_source is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Please use $source instead.
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for ubuntu.localdomain in environment production in 0.71 seconds
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/Apt::Setting[conf-update-stamp]/File[/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}0962d70c4ec78bbfa6f3544ae0c41974'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[preferences]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs::Repo::Nodesource/Nodejs::Repo::Nodesource::Apt/Apt::Source[nodesource]/Apt::Key[Add key: 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280 from Apt::Source nodesource]/Apt_key[Add key: 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280 from Apt::Source nodesource]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs::Repo::Nodesource/Nodejs::Repo::Nodesource::Apt/Apt::Source[nodesource]/Apt::Setting[list-nodesource]/File[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]/returns: E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Failed to call refresh: /usr/bin/apt-get update returned 100 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: /usr/bin/apt-get update returned 100 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nodejs::Install/Package[nodejs]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 29.83 seconds
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Thu Nov 19 06:46:10 2015 from 172.16.42.1
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ node -v
v0.6.12
```

Comment: getting the same issue, i destroyed the box and ran vagrant up. command line confirmed that the new package was installed - 
==> default: /etc/puppet/modules
==> default: puppetlabs-nodejs (v0.8.0)

Comment: which version of puppet are you using ?

Comment: I am running 3.4.3, will look into updating the puppet version and see what happens though i have also post another solution. Which may or may not be a better way.

Comment: I used this http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/upgrading-puppet-in-vagrant-boxes/ to update the version of puppet on a provision. Puppet is now running v3.8.4 and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

--- This is an alternative method

This took a while to de-bug but the best approach I found to installing node on a server through puppet is to run a manual instal through puppet.

I found this [repo](https://github.com/joaquimserafim/vagrant-nodejs-redis-mongodb/blob/master/vagrant/puppet/manifests/main.pp), and took what I needed from the manifest file.

```
class apt_update {
    exec { "aptGetUpdate":
        command => "sudo apt-get update",
        path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin"]
    }
}

class othertools {
    package { "git":
        ensure => latest,
        require => Exec["aptGetUpdate"]
    }

    package { "vim-common":
        ensure => latest,
        require => Exec["aptGetUpdate"]
    }

    package { "curl":
        ensure => present,
        require => Exec["aptGetUpdate"]
    }

    package { "htop":
        ensure => present,
        require => Exec["aptGetUpdate"]
    }

    package { "g++":
        ensure => present,
        require => Exec["aptGetUpdate"]
    }
}

class nodejs {
  exec { "git_clone_n":
    command => "git clone https://github.com/visionmedia/n.git /home/vagrant/n",
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin"],
    require => [Exec["aptGetUpdate"], Package["git"], Package["curl"], Package["g++"]]
  }

  exec { "install_n":
    command => "make install",
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin"],
    cwd => "/home/vagrant/n",
    require => Exec["git_clone_n"]
  }

  exec { "install_node":
    command => "n stable",
    path => ["/bin", "/usr/bin", "/usr/local/bin"],
    require => [Exec["git_clone_n"], Exec["install_n"]]
  }
}

include apt_update
include othertools
include nodejs
```